# How do i solve that math problem with infinite iterations

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic

Sorry for my possible imperfect translation of that problem, i was asked that on my interview for junior data analyst and couldn't solve it correctly.

Vasya usually spends one hour for cleaning up his mess. He discovered Pareto principle: 80% of consequences come from 20% of the causes. So he decided to clean up 80% of his mess in 20% of usual time, then clean up 80% of remaining mess in 20% of time that it should have taken and he kept doing that till all the mess is cleaned. Note that he cleans evenly so for example 20% of the mess he cleans in 20% time that it would take.
How much time could he save?

My solution was the following. First he cleans 80% of the mess. Usually it would take $0.8 *60=48$ mins but he does in 20% time so in $0.8*60*0.2$. Then he has 20% of mess remaining and he cleans 80% of it in 20% time: $0.16*60*0.2$. Then the time will be $0.032*60*0.2$. We can see the pattern. So overall time will be
$(0.8 + 0.16 + 0.032 + \dots) * 60 * 0.2= \frac{0.8}{1 - 0.2}*60*0.2=60*0.2=12$
So the answer is 48. I understand that this is strange that answer is just $60*0.2$ but i can't see what am i missing. I was only provided with right answer.

Comment: In he end, every part of the mess is cleaned up in $20\%$ of the usual time, so it takes $20\%$ of the usual time to finish.

Comment: So you say my answer is correct? But i was told that right answer is 45 minutes

Comment: I get $48$ for the reason I said.  Unless I am missing something (always possible) it is quite simple:   He is carving up the cleaning into a bunch of disjoint tasks.  He completes each of those tasks in $20\%$ of his usual time, so the whole job takes $20\%$ of his usual time.  I don't see where the extra $3$ minutes could have come from.